# Angular material Treeview collapse/expand check box not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview, material-design, angular-material

Angular Material `Tree view` `Checkbox` is working fine when i try to collapse/expand first time and `checked` whether on `Parent Node` or `Child Node`, but it is not working when i try to `Checked` the different `node` (i.e.`Child Node`) on second time. I use custom directive to achieve `Tree View` functionality. Below is my Code.

**Custom Directive**

```
NFSModule.directive('nfsTree', function () {
    return {     
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            tree: '=source',
        },
        template: '<nfs-node ng-repeat="c in tree.children" cnode="c"></nfs-node>'
    };
});

NFSModule.directive('nfsNode', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            node: '=cnode'
        },
        template: '<li><span ng-click="toggleVisibility(node)"> {{ ( node.childrenVisibility && node.children.length ) ? "+" : "-" }}</span>' +
    '<nfs-tree-checkbox ng-model="node.checked" ng-click="checkNode(node)"><span ng-bind="node.name"></span></nfs-tree-checkbox></li>', // HTML for a single node.
        link: function (scope, element) {
            /*
             * Here we are checking that if current node has children then compiling/rendering children.
             * */
            if (scope.node && scope.node.children && scope.node.children.length > 0) {
                scope.node.childrenVisibility = true;
                var childNode = $compile('<ul ng-if="!node.childrenVisibility"><nfs-tree source="node" ></nfs-tree></ul>')(scope);
                element.append(childNode);
            } else {
                scope.node.childrenVisibility = false;
            }
        },
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            // This function is for just toggle the visibility of children
            $scope.toggleVisibility = function (node) {
                if (node.children) {
                    node.childrenVisibility = !node.childrenVisibility;
                }
            };
            // Here We are marking check/un-check all the nodes.
            $scope.checkNode = function (selectednode) {

                if (selectednode.checked != undefined) {
                    var has_child = angular.isArray(selectednode.children);
                    if (has_child = true)
                    {
                        checkChildren(selectednode);
                    }
                }
                function checkChildren(c) {
                    angular.forEach(c.children, function (c) {
                        c.checked = selectednode.checked;

                    });

                }
            };
        }]
    };
});

NFSModule.directive('nfsTreeCheckbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
            ngClick: '=',
            ngDisabled: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        template: function (elem, attr) {
            return '<md-input-container class="md-inline" style="height:10px !important; margin-top:-5px; !important; margin-left:5px !important;">' +
            '<md-checkbox ng-model="ngModel" ng-click="ngClick" ng-disabled="ngDisabled" aria-label="{{label}}" class="md-primary">' +
               '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
            ' </md-checkbox>' +
            '</md-input-container>'
        }
    };
});
```

**$SCOPE**

```
$scope.location = {
        children:
            [
                     {
                          name: 'Europe',
                          children: [
                              {
                                  name: 'Italy',
                                  children: [
                                      {
                                          name: 'Rome'
                                      },
                                      { name: 'Milan' }
                                  ]
                              },
                              { name: 'Spain' }
                          ]
                      },
                   {
                       name: 'South America',
                       children: [
                           { name: 'Brasil' },
                           { name: 'Peru' }
                       ]
                   }
              ]
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<ul >
    <nfs-tree source="location"></nfs-tree>
</ul>
```